# When closing the Modal from child object I get Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap modal to wrap a form that captures some data and posts to an api.

I have 2 components: Modal and the form inside. I want to close the modal and return to the main page when the submit is successful. For this purpose I am passing a handleClose function from parent modal component to child component, but whenever the child calls that function, I get the warning.

Parent modal Component:

```
function NotesModal(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    return (
        <>
                <CustomToolTip id="new-note" text="Add Notes">
                    <Button variant="light" size='sm'onClick={handleShow}>
                        <RiPlayListAddLine   />
                    </Button>
                </CustomToolTip>
       

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Add or Update Notes</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body><AddNewNoteForm data={props.data} handleClose={handleClose}/></Modal.Body>

            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
export default NotesModal
```

And here the child component Form:

```
const AddNewNoteForm = (props) => {
    const { data, handleClose } = props
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false)

  
    useEffect(()=>{
        return () => console.log('unmounted')
    },[])

    const initialValues = {
        note: data.poNotes || ''
    }
    const { handleSubmit, control, errors, formState, reset, setError } = useForm({
        mode: "onChange",
        reValidateMode: "onChange",
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
        defaultValues: initialValues
    })


    const { isDirty, isValid, isSubmitSuccessful } = formState;
    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        const params = { object: 'prodOrder', note: e.note, id: data.prodOrderId }
        try {
            const response = await postNotes(params)
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                handleClose();
            }, 1500)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setError('service', { type: 'serversideerror', message: 'Notlar kaydedilirken bir hata oluştu.' })
            console.log(errors)
        }
    }
    return (<Form>...</Form>)
}
```

Appreciate if anybody could help to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: The state you're using in that child component is the `isSubmitted` but it's not being used anywhere or you intentionally omitted it because it's not relevant and couldn't be causing the problem.  Remove the `useState` and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I removed it but it did not help. I am still getting the error. I think its because of closing the modal before the child component is unmounted, but couldn't find a way to do it correctly.